# Border removal after Canny edge detection

Tags: python, opencv, edge-detection, canny-operator

My problem is to detect whether the page is blank or not. The approach I have followed is to remove Gaussian noise and apply Canny edge detection. The last step I would like to do is remove the border . A hacky solution i thought of is to just crop the image but it there are some cases which will border in between. 
Could you share any ideas you have to remove the borders/lines?

`im_gray = cv2.imread(curFile, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(im_gray,(5,5),0)
edges = cv2.Canny(blur,100,200)`

example image:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/7zjpvlg42tsunxi/nlin.jpg?dl=0

Comment: Great. And ... what's the question? There's no question mark in the whole text.

Comment: sorry. I forgot about it. Added the question